# Make label translatable in Global: Custom Text field

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I'm using Drupal 7 and I have a Global: Custom Text in my view

```
<div class="myclass">
  <h3>Label</h3>
  <div class="title">[title]</div>
  <div class="category">[category]</div> 
</div>
```

When I try to translate the 'Label' from

```
`Configuration » Regional and language » Translate interface`
```

I get an error 'The submitted string contains disallowed HTML'.
That is because the label is wrapped in a div. I could add the div in include/locale.inc in the function

```
`locale_string_is_safe($string)`
```

but I don't think is a good idea to edit the Drupal core.

Do you have any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use `hook_views_pre_view` and set your global header programmatically.
E.g.

```
$view->set_item_option($view->current_display, 'header', 'area_text_custom', 'content', $header);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a template for the field, i.e.

**views-view-field--your-view-name--nothing.tpl.php**

in which, instead of the default code:

```
print $output;
```

you add the following code:

```
$yourstr = t('Your Cool Label');
$out = str_replace('Your Cool Label', $yourstr, $output);
print $out;
```

In this way you'll find "Your Cool Label" under the translatable strings interface (admin/config/regional/translate/translate).

Just remember to "Rescan template files" under Theme -> Information of your view, then save.